# From which page navigated to a given page

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, back-button

I want to know from which page navigated to a given page by pressing the back button. But I didn't find a solution for it in WP8.1 
Parameters can be used for forwards navigation, as I know.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know which page was displayed before the user navigated back to your current page? You can inspect `Frame.ForwardStack` for that:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
    {
        // get the type of the page that was shown previously
        var navigatedFromPage = Frame.ForwardStack[0].SourcePageType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was the question. And your solution works fine! Thanks